# Analytical approximation of the ODE: $\alpha y y'' = - y+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I would like to achieve an approximate solution to the following 2nd-order non-linear ODE of y(t):

$\alpha y y'' = - y +1$

Where $\alpha>0$ is a constant, and the initial conditions are as follows:

$y(0) = \beta>0$

$y'(0) = 0$

Solving it numerically with MATLAB yields a solution which reminds a cosinusoidal wave with an increasing amplitude. That is except for the case $\beta=1$, then the solution is simply $y(t) = 1$. From the numerical solution, it seems that the approximation will have the form:

$y = 1 + A cos(\omega t)$

Where the amplitude is $A = A(\beta,t)$ and $\omega = \omega(\beta)$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you know about $\alpha$. Is it small?

Comment: Actually, you can define $\tau = t/\sqrt{\alpha}$ and get rid of the dependence of $\alpha$. Perhaps an expansion for small departures of $\beta = 1$ is useful here to give you an idea of how the amplitude (and frequency) changes with $\beta$. That is, you may want to consider $\beta = 1 + \epsilon$ and expand about $\epsilon \to 0$. You'll find that $y(\tau) \approx 1 + (\beta-1) \cos \tau$, which fits reasonably well for $\epsilon$ up to $0.2$ or so. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on this.

Comment: For my current needs, $\alpha$ is in the range $0.2<\alpha<1$, but it's not a demand. Could you please elaborate on your last result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a follow up of my comment.

First thing that one may notice is the fact that $\alpha$ plays an *stretching* role on the temporal coordinate. If one defines the rescaled time $\tau = t/\sqrt{\alpha}$, the problem reduces to

$$ y y'' = 1-y, \quad y(0) = \beta > 0, \quad y'(0) = 0 $$

As you mentioned, for $\beta = 1$, $y = 1$ is a solution to the problem. Now the primes denote differentiation with respect to $\tau$. If one is interested in values of $\beta$ close to $1$ (a similar analysis can be carried out for $\beta$ close to $0$, for instance), that is for $\beta = 1 + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ small, a solution of the form

$$ y = 1 + \epsilon y_1 + \epsilon^2 y_2 + \ldots $$

may be sought. Note that $y_i'(0)=0$ and $y_1(0) = 1, \ y_{i>1}(0) = 0$ are the corresponding initial conditions for each new variable. By introducing this into the original equation and collecting powers of $\epsilon$ one arrives at

\begin{align}
\epsilon^0: \quad & 1 = 1 \\
\epsilon^1: \quad & y_1'' + y_1 = 0 \\
\epsilon^2: \quad & y_2'' + y_2 = -y_1 y_1'' \\
\vdots
\end{align} The solution to these problems (with the corresponding initial conditions) is

$$y_1(\tau) = \cos \tau , \quad y_2 = \frac{2}{3} ( 2 + \cos\tau ) \sin^2(\tau/2)$$

for which a first order correction of your solution is

$$ y = 1 + (\beta - 1) \cos \tau + \mathcal{O}[(\beta - 1)^2]$$

and a second order approximation is

$$ y = 1 + (\beta - 1) \cos \tau + \frac{2}{3}(\beta - 1)^2 ( 2 + \cos\tau ) \sin^2(\tau/2) +  \mathcal{O}[(\beta - 1)^3] $$

where I have put $\epsilon = \beta - 1$. Note that the first order correction to the solution works reasonably well even for values of $\epsilon$ up to $0.3$. Here's a plot (blue is the numerical solution and should be $\tau$ in the abscissa label)

[image]

---

I edited my comment because I missed a $y_1$ on the rhs of the equation for $y_2$, which completely changes the story...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, actually I had learned multiple-scale analysis 4 years ago and I never thought that I'll have to use it again. It's very helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help! @Shahar

Answer (score 3):

multiply all the sides by $ y'(t)$ and you get

$ \alpha (y' (t))^{2}=-2y(t)+ 2 \log y(t) +C$

here C is a constant of integration

Comment: Isn't it $2\log{y}$?

Comment: When you derivate the expression (let's say it's $2logy$ as suggested above), you get:
$2 \alpha\ y' y'' = -2y' + 2y'/y$
Multiplying it by $y$, you get:
$2 \alpha\ y' y'' y = -2y' y + 2y'$

Dividing by $2y'$:
$ \alpha\ y'' y = - y + 1$

Which seems to be a true and crucial step, but how to continue from here to approximate y(x)?

Comment: Moreover, the value of $C$ is given by $2 (\beta-\log{\beta})$